# Can I send NFC readings (Android Phone) to a program on my PC (Windows) which will paste text in whatever text box I have selected?

Tags: android, windows, text, nfc, send

I'm not really good at developing myself and I would really like to set up some sort of NFC readings to PC like program. I don't know how to explain this because all the articles I went through didn't have any useful info. I found this Virtual Smart Card reader that you had to build in Visual Studio but it didn't even work since the .sln file was out dated and needed all sorts of old SDK's and other things. My goal is to basically get some program on my android phone (Samsung Galaxy A20) and something on my PC that pastes text received from the NFC reader in the phone. If someone could possibly help me with my issue, I would be very pleased.

Thanks, Daniel

Edit: I don't really program so already made programs preferred please

Answer (score 0):

So possible to implement what you need but a lot of programming work on the PC and or Android Phone.

Some USB PC NFC readers that come with PC software that will read a NFC card UID and be a virtual keyboard and type the UID in to any PC program BUT you are probably not after just using the UID of a NFC card so it gets more complicated.

To send data one device needs to pretend to be a card with Host Card Emulation (NCE) and the other device needs to read a card.

All Android phone will do HCE (no iOS phone does HCE), some PC readers do HCE.

While some PC readers also do peer to peer Android has dropped support for this in Android 10 and iOS does not support it.

So to send data you will need to write custom programs both Android and PC and programming HCE support is quite advanced and on the PC side you you might depending on the exact requirements had to do the virtual keyboard stuff but might get away with manual cut and paste.

More details on the data you are trying to send would help narrow down the problem, but NFC is not good for larger amounts of data, where Bluetooth or Wifi Direct would be better.

Comment: Im not good very good at coding and would prefer a pre-made app if possible. Do you know where to find "said" app?
edit - thank you for the reply but as i said, not good at coding /: